# What is the name of this matching problem?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, approximation, weighted-graphs, bipartite-matching

We have a bipartite graph consisting of parts $A$ and $B$. Each vertex $i$ of part $A$ has weight $w_i$ and capacity $c_i$. We say a vertex $i$ in part $A$ is satisfied if at least $c_i$ adjacent edges to it are chosen. Now, the goal is to choose some edges of this graph such that each vertex in $B$ is adjacent to at most 1 chosen edge, and the sum of the weight of the satisfied vertices is maximized.

What is the name of this problem? Do you know any papers about it?
Reducing this problem to a famous problem is helpful.